# Can't use terminal, I keep getting "zsh: command not found: npm" even after an OS re-install

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, npm, macos-sonoma

I don't remember what I had done, but every time I attempt to run a command (`npm install -g gulp`) in terminal, it returns a `zsh: command not found: npm`. This is a command I previously had no issue executing before.

I performed a clean install of OSX (Sonoma 14.4) and the problem still persists. So I am convinced this is default behavior and not user error.

Comment: Is Node JS installed? No need to reinstall the whole OS when it is just one binary like `npm` which is a part of Node JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, install homebrew on you mac using the following command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Now, you can use homebrew to install nodejs on your mac.

```
brew install node
```

You can now use npm to install gulp or any other modules as npm and nodejs are part of the node package.

Comment: Yes, this got me over the hump in being able to install the package, but other simple commands such as `dir` or `list` still result in a `zsh: command not found`

Comment: Use `ls` command for listing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69768619